# Как сделать ввод с клавиатуры input date на телефоне

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть `input`:

```html
<input type="date" name="birth">
```

В браузере на компьютере я могу ввести дату и с помощью клавиатуры, и с помощью календаря.

На телефоне же при нажатии на `input` появляется календарь. Мне нужно, чтобы на телефоне был тоже ввод и с календаря, и с клавиатуры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это осуществить?

Comment: Видимо только двумя дублирующими друг друга input. Так, чтобы date было скрыто, а календарь вызывался нажатием на иконку в <label>. Выбранное значение даты может копироваться в редактируемое текстовое поле. Но надо позаботиться о маске ввода... Сложно, короч

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Да, я тоже так думал, это был лучший вариант, что я придумал, но я никак не могу сделать вызов календаря через js... Может вы знаете? Это же просто иконка, я к ней обращаюсь только в css с помощью `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` чтобы `background` указать

Comment: `<input type="date" id="dateInput" style="width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0; -webkit-appearance:none"><label for="dateInput">...</label>` —  нажатие на label отдает фокус в input и вызывает стандартный календарь iOS и Android

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Спасибо вам большое! То что нужно